# How to capture App Screen as Video with Audio in Mac OSX?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, nsview, avcapturesession

I am writing a MacOS or OSX application where I need to record **only the View**  of my application (Not the Whole display) with the Audio it emits.

Think it as a game app and I need to record the complete GamePlay View Of the Application.How should I go about doing this?

I am aware of "**AVCaptureScreenInput**" and, the [example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1740/_index.html). But how to capture only the view of my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the website you posted:

> Note: By default, `AVCaptureScreenInput` captures the entire screen. You may set its `cropRect` property to limit the capture rectangle to a subsection of the screen.

Just set this property to the windows/views rect and you're done

Of course you need to update and restart the recording when the windows/views rect changes.

Comment: But, how do we detect which Display the application is running on? For example, I have two displays, and the application might run on the Big Secondary Display.

Answer (score 0):

Read the document carefully, there is a comment, about the displays:

// If you're on a multi-display system and you want to capture a secondary display,
    // you can call CGGetActiveDisplayList() to get the list of all active displays.
    // For this example, we just specify the main display.
    // To capture both a main and secondary display at the same time, use two active
    // capture sessions, one for each display. On Mac OS X, AVCaptureMovieFileOutput
    // only supports writing to a single video track.